# How can I display values from relationship on column array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 tables (users and meetings).

I'm trying to displaying the name of the user on table index view

```
users
 |id|   |name|
  1      DEMO 1
  2      DEMO 2
  3      DEMO 3

meetings
 |id|    |user_id|
  1      ["1", "2"]
  2      ["2"]
  3      ["2", "3"]
```

The Controller /app/controllers/meetings_controller.erb

```
def index
  @meetings = Meeting.all
end
```

Models

```
#meeting.rb
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
end

#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :meetings
end
```

The View /app/views/meetings/index.html.erb

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>User Names</td>
   </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
   <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= meeting.id %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.user_id %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to display the user_id on array relationship and i tried this code:

I got the following error using the following code

```
 undefined method `each' for "[\"1\", \"2\"]":String

 <% meeting.user_id do |array|%>
   <%= array.user.name %>
 <% end %>
```

I got the following error using the following code

```
 undefined method `each' for "[\"1\", \"2\"]":String

 <% meeting.user_id do |array|%>
   <%= array %>
 <% end %>
```

I cannot display the value relationship because of column array.

Can you please help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information to suggest you a fix. Please explain what and how are user_id saved in Meeting. Is it array? Is it has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Comment: user_id its an array.

Comment: Which database are you using? Also, what is displayed on rails console when you do: `meeting.user_id`.

Comment: Its displaying this:  ["1","2"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is nothing wrong with your approach, one comes to understand that the path of least resistance (= least pain) is to follow "The Rails Way".

So instead of answering your question, let me suggest that the relationship between your models should be:

```rb
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings
end

# meeting.rb
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

# you will also need to create a join table with a migration:
def change
 create_join_table :meetings, :users
end
```

Then the view will include:

```rb
   <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= meeting.id %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.users.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: I followed your code and instructions and its not displaying values, its blank

Comment: @CarlosMorales ok so you need to figure out why! In the rails console, if you type `Meeting.first` what is the response? If you type `Meeting.first.users` what is the response? How are you creating the database contents? Is the users table populated? Is the meetings table populated? Is the meetings_users table populated (you may have to use mysql to determine this, unless you have created a `MeetingsUser` model). What does the schema.rb look like for the users table, the meetings table, and the join table?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a `has_many` relation between `Meeting` and `User`. That means that `meeting.users` will return the list of the users for the current meeting.

The following will return a comma-separated string with the names.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>User Names</td>
   </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
   <% @meetings.each do |meeting| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= meeting.id %></td>
      <td><%= meeting.users.map(&:name).join(', ') %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Its not working. how should be the model configuration?